# ActiveRecord query using a two dimentional array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can anyone help me in this issue, Like I have two dimensional array like this

```
array = [[1, 'go'], [15, 'flat']........]
```

And I have table in the database called FeedPost, now in the 2D array the first element in each array means to a column user_id and the second one means to the column feed_type. Now I want to get all the records from that table that fulfills that array elements exactly matches to these exact column. in other word i wanted do something like that,

```
FeedPost.find_all_by_user_id_and_feed_type(array)
```

but unfortunately it shows following argument error.

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

So anyone can help me in this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be:

```
FeedPost.where(user_id: array.map(&:first)).where(feed_type: array.map(&:last))
```

this will split your array into two arrays, one containing the user_ids and one containing the feed_types, and query the feed posts accordingly using an IN SQL statement.

EDIT: this will bring any all records that have any combination of user_id and feed_type from the array. If you want only records that only satisfy both user_id and feed_type from a single item in the array, this won't work.

Comment: with your syntax, you allow a record `{ user_id: 1, feed_type: 'flat' }` to match. Its not desired

Comment: Correct. I just added this as an EDIT.

Comment: try your query, you'll get zero result: its an `AND` chaining

Comment: Correct again. I'll remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `any_of` [gem](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of), then:

```
queries = array.map {|sub_array| FeedPost.where({ user_id: sub_array[0], feed_type: sub_array[1] }) }
FeedPost.where.any_of(*queries)
```

Comment: i am getting this error ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Comment: I need more info, no idea what happens

Comment: i hope you will understand what i am trying to do, its a method in a model `def leader_posts
    array = []
    self.supports.each do |s|
      array << [s.leader_id, s.political_issue_id]      
    end    
    queries = array.map {|sub_array| FeedPost.where({ user_id: sub_array[0], political_issue_id: sub_array[1] })}
    FeedPost.where.any_of(*queries)
  end` @apneadiving